# jQuery mouseenter and mouseleave

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make logout system for my users by a kind of dropdown. When the user hovers on his name a dropdown opens and when he leaves the div, it hides by jQuery. I have tried to do this with mouseenter and mouseleave function, but it seems not to be working. Please refer to my jsfiddle file at http://jsfiddle.net/b6K2R/

The following is my code:-

HTML

```
<div id="ppic" style="float:right;position:relative;" class="top" href="#"> 
<img style="float:left;" src="https://graph.facebook.com/100005546162517/picture"
width="25" height="25"> 
<span style="float:left;margin:4px 0 0 5px;">
Deval
</span>
<div class="submenu">
<ul class="root">
<li ><a href="settings" >Settings</a></li>
<li ><a href="Logout" >Logout</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".submenu").hide();
});
$("#ppic").mouseenter(function(){
$(".submenu").show();
});
$("#ppic").mouseleave(function(){
$(".submenu").hide();
});
```

CSS :-

```
.submenu
{
background: #fff;
position: absolute;
top: 41px;
right: 0px;
z-index: 1;
width: 125px;
margin-left: 10px;
padding: 0px 0 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
}
.top li a 
{
color: #555555;
display: block;
font-family: arial;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 10px 15px 10px 20px;
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration:none;
outline:none;
}

.top li a:hover
{
background:#155FB0;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
}
.root
{
list-style:none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
font-size: 11px;
}
```

Please help me...! Thanks in advance... :>

Comment: you forgot to include jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/b6K2R/1/

Comment: Ya, also saw missing jQuery, but thought that it isn't a problem. I though the problem is that the window disappears quickly.. it's because it's not included in #ppic .. check the red area here: http://jsfiddle.net/b6K2R/3/

Comment: yes...the window disappears...please tell me how to solve it... @Dampe

Comment: @Deval Khandelwal: Sry, was afk. It seems that kyle.stearns has already posted working solution in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hover over the `#ppic` element it displays the `.submenu` element. When you move your mouse away/out of the `#ppic` element it will hide the `.submenu` element.

It is working exactly how you coded it. The problem is that there is a gap between the `#ppic` element and the submenu. Therefore when you try to move your mouse to the `.submenu` element it registers as a `mouseout` on the `#ppic` element.

Try adjusting the `top` property for `.submenu` in your CSS to move the `.submenu` closer to the `#ppic` element.

I modified the `top` value to be `top:25px` and it worked properly.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b6K2R/5/

Comment: If I want to keep the CSS? Can you give me a jQuery approach?

Comment: something like a css menu could help http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

Comment: @user1479606 I've modified the CSS here but it has the same aesthetic as your original approach. I did this by creating a wrapper `div` element around the submenu and using padding to provide the gap in between the `#ppic` element and `.submenu`. http://jsfiddle.net/b6K2R/6/

Answer (score 0):

You must set "Frameworks & Extensions" be "jQuery x(version)". It's work.